# Creating JSON file using NSDictionary with an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsdictionary

I am attempting to create [json](/questions/tagged/json) data to send to a server via an HTTP POST request. The [server](http://www.mandrill.com) will only accept a specific format of JSON, otherwise it will return an error. I can successfully create and upload the JSON file to the server, however I am getting the following error because I have not formatted my JSON incorrectly:

```
JSON Error Message: {
    code = "-2";
    message = "Validation error: {\"message\":{\"to\":[\"Please enter an array\"]}}";
    name = ValidationError;
    status = error;
}
```

As you can see, the server needs a complex JSON format with an Array of Values and Keys but I'm not sure how to do that. Below is my current code to create the JSON data:

```
//Create Array With TO Values
NSDictionary *toField = @{@"email" : emailField.text};
//Create Dictionary Values                
NSDictionary *messageContent = @{@"subject" : @"APPNAME Registration Complete", @"from_email" : @"email@domain.com", @"to" : toField};
NSDictionary *mandrillValues = @{@"key" : @"APPKEY",
                                 @"redirect_url" : @"PRIVATE-URL",
                                 @"template_name" : @"app-registration",
                                 @"template_content" : [NSNull null],
                                 @"message" : messageContent
                                };

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mandrillValues options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
```

According to the server, I need an array with keys and values, similar to a [nsdictionary](/questions/tagged/nsdictionary). **When I use an NSArray, though, I can't add values / keys. Any ideas on how I should go about doing this?** Below is an [example of the JSON format](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html#method=send-template) that the server will accept, am I doing everything right to follow this format? If not, what do I need to change to match the format?

```
{
"key": "example key",
"template_name": "example template_name",
"template_content": [
    {
        "name": "example name",
        "content": "example content"
    }
],
"message": {
    "text": "example text",
    "subject": "example subject",
    "from_email": "message.from_email@example.com",
    "from_name": "example from_name",
    "to": [
        {
            "email": "example email",
            "name": "example name"
        }
    ],
}}
```

Comment: Think like an algorithm. You start from the beginning: What do you got? `{` indicates the enclosed part is a dictionary, `[` indicates the enclosed part is an array. Think like that and create your JSON in a similar manner. So a JSON dictionary will also be a NSDictionary. A JSON array will also be a NSArray. A good way to figure this out, is to serialize the example you got and see what data structures are used. Good luck! :)

Comment: Serializing the original JSON before sending is a good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the "to" field expects an array. Unless the variable `toField` is an NSArray that contains dictionaries with keys and values as described, you're going to get a JSON that's not exactly like the one you want.

I would suggest outputting the description of the outgoing JSON to see exactly where there are differences.

**Update**
I saw the addition to your question -

```
NSDictionary *toField = @{@"email" : emailField.text};
```

Does not create an array. Try:

```
NSArray *toField = @[@{@"email" : emailField.text}];
```

Comment: Great! I didn't think of placing NSDictionaries inside of NSArrays. Is that possible?